# Unable to update to Xcode6 from AppStore

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode, software-update

I am running my mac on OSX 10.9.5
I can see Xcode 6 in the app store and there is a button "Update".
But once I hit the update button, spinner pops up for a second and then dissappears and that's it.

No warning or dialog or anything...It just doesn't do anything.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it ?

Comment: Just move Xcode to the trash bin and try installing it clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen with other apps in the past and what works for me is to:

- kick off a Time Machine backup (or equivalent)
- delete the app using Launchpad (or deleting from from /Applications)
- restart

The restart is probably not needed in the vast majority of cases, but it ensures that no files from the app are still open from any process still running.

At that point, the app store should have a good shot to install the app (Xcode in your case).